# Moving my access application with SQL server back end to sharepoint

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm currently thinking of migrating my MS Access (connected to a SQL Server 2008 database) applications to SharePoint 2010 in order to have the freedom to access/edit the data anywhere.

My question is.. How big a task is it to move the data from my SQL Server database to the SharePoint server?

Has anyone done this before? I'm still researching SharePoint therefore any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how complex are your forms in Access and the complexity of the manipulation you want to do with your data. If it is a simple data model then you can go easily with the BCS in SharePoint. Further to customize the forms you can use Infopath designer if you are not much familiar with ASP.Net.